# Does a LaTeX to Kramdown converter exist?

Tags: conversion, html, markdown

I'm building a blog using Jekyll and hosting on Github Pages. I have a bunch of LaTeX documents that I'd like to upload as blog posts, but they contain a good deal of formatting that I'd have to go in and edit to make compatible with KramDown. For example, if I have `\newline` or `\textit` in LaTeX, I'd have to manually change those to `\\\` and `\*text\*` in KramDown. I saw that KramDown has a built-in converter that will format markup into a Latex PDF output, but are there any tools in existence that will do the opposite?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Regarding your question, you might want to have a look at [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) which will convert between a lot of formats, including MarkDown and LaTeX.

Comment: if you have existing LaTeX documents then it's nonsense to convert them to Markdown. You can convert them directly to HTML using `tex4ht`. You only need to replace HTML header with YAML header in these HTMLs.  [jekyll4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/jekyll4ht) can be used to automatize this.

Comment: LaTeX to *down is harder than you might think (and no lightweight markup language is as expressive as *TeX). If the goal is to get to HTML, then use `tex4ht` to convert your LaTeX files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out `text4ht` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `jekyll` and majority of other static site generators support `HTML` files with `YAML` frontmatter, it seems as better approach to me to convert LaTeX to `HTML` and modify it to the needed form. For example, `tex4ht` can be configured to produce the `YAML` frontmatter directly, and we can use `make4ht` library to create helper script, which will copy the `HTML`, `CSS` and image files to correct locations. The project is named [jekyll4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/jekyll4ht).

It can be used as following:

Create following structure

```
pathtoblog
  jekyllsite
     _posts
     img
     css
  texfiles
     .jekyll4ht
     firstpost
       firstpost.tex
```

your generated files will be copied to the `jekyllsite`, which must be configured in `.jekyll4ht` configuration file. It's minimal contents should be:

```
base="pathtoblog/jekyllsite/"
```

You can then create documents in `texfiles` directory, and publish them with

```
jekyll4ht -m publish filename.tex
```

when they are done. Note that this doesn't rebuild your site, it must be done manually using `jekyll serve` from `jekyllsite`.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this! I like that it's jekyll specific.

Answer (score 4):

@michal.h21 has provided a sensible approach that doesn't require converting from tex -> markdown. If you do want to convert a tex file to markdown/kramdown, [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) can do that. For example:

```
pandoc source.tex -o source.md
```

Some caveats to keep in mind:

1. Markdown doesn't support all the formatting provided by LaTeX, so you may lose something in the conversion
2. Kramdown is a superset of Markdown. the PHP-extra extensions are supported by pandoc, but there may be other things that are not.

Some of the commenters have indicated that this conversion is silly. However, if you have a site that mixes articles typeset in LaTeX and Markdown, the resulting blog posts may be inconsistent. That is, the ones produced via tex4ht may have different formatting than those from markdown. Depending on the number of articles, and the extent of the formatting in the LaTeX source files, it *may* be easiest to deal with this by reducing everything to markdown format. (Or you may prefer going the other way, converting all your markdown into LaTeX).